# OnClick missing in LinkButton controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the ProductID from the Linkbutton I click on, but I cant find an OnClick choice, just the OnClientClick, but it dont works, are there another way to do it?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = CategoryAccess.GetAllProducts();

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        LinkButton lbDelete = new LinkButton();
        lbDelete.Text = table.Rows[i]["ProductName"].ToString();
        lbDelete.ID = table.Rows[i]["ProductID"].ToString();
        lbDelete.CommandArgument = table.Rows[i]["ProductID"].ToString();
        lbDelete.OnClientClick = "btnDelete_Click";


        phDelete.Controls.Add(lbDelete);
     }
 }

    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton _sender = (LinkButton)sender;
        string TrixID = _sender.CommandArgument;

        DeleteProduct(ProductID);
    }
```

Comment: You need to understand and use event handlers. But your code calls more for a Repeater object in your ASP.NET.aspx. And even more for a grid.

Comment: Yes I know how to do it in a Repeater but I thought I missed something when I couldnt find an OnClick event in codebehind.

Comment: I can't believe that you have found the `OnClientClick` but you haven't found the `Click` event in the `LinkButton` (?)

Comment: Yes, I found that aswell, I get an error if I use click: The event 'Click' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think I understand what you are doing, but going about it in a funny way.

What I usually do i scode the rowcommand event.  I add commandargs='<%# Eval("Id") %>' (or something like that) and pass it to the rowcommand event where I then grab e.commandargs and use that value to delete the database row.

here is one of many examples of what I' talking about

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewConfirmDelete.aspx

Sorry if this isn't helpful.